# How to use xy coordinates to get data from SQLite db?

Tags: java, android-studio, coordinates

I have an SQLite database that contains x y coordinates of specific points in an image (Aya_No)  among other data, I would like to get information from the db regrading these specific points (Aya_No) on LongPress

Here is part of the db:
[image]

Here is a sample image:
[image]

I have managed to get screen width and height using this code:

```
 public static int getScreenX (Context context){
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int maxWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        return  maxWidth;
    }

    public static int getScreenY (Context context){
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        int maxHight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        return  maxHight;
    }
```

and I have managed to get x y OnTouchListener and pass it to OnLongClickListener using this code:

```
 view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                return false;
            }
        });

        view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                double Talorance = 25;
                double screenX = Utils.getScreenX(context);
                double screenY = Utils.getScreenY(context);

                // Adjusted x
                double xPer = x/Utils.getScreenX(context); // .315
                double adjXMin = (x - Talorance) * xPer;
                double adjXMax = (x + Talorance) * xPer;

                // Adjusted y
                double yPer = y/Utils.getScreenY(context);  //.33
                double adjYMin = (y - Talorance) * yPer;
                double adjYMax = (y + Talorance) * yPer;

                String ScreenXY = String.format("ScreenXY: (%.2f, %.2f)",screenX, screenY);
                String ClickedXY = String.format("ClickedXY: (%.2f, %.2f)",x,y);
                String AdjustedMin = String.format("AdjustedMinXY: (%.2f, %.2f)",adjXMin,adjYMin);
                String AdjustedMax = String.format("AdjustedMaxXY: (%.2f, %.2f)",adjXMax,adjYMax);
                Log.w("ScreenXY", ScreenXY);
                Log.w("ClickedXY ", ClickedXY);
                Log.w("MinXY", AdjustedMin);
                Log.w("MaxXY",AdjustedMax);

                int page = lastpage - QuranActivity.mCurrentPage;
                return true;
            }
        });
```

the results of the last code after longPress of Ayah 1 (circled in red in the 1st image) is:

```
W/ScreenXY: ScreenXY: (1440.00, 2712.00)
W/ClickedXY: ClickedXY: (574.98, 1064.89)
W/MinXY: AdjustedMinXY: (219.60, 408.32)
W/MaxXY: AdjustedMaxXY: (239.57, 427.96)
```

while the x y of this particular point in the db is 181, 301

after the long details above and bearing in mind that what I am asking for is actually implemented in many apps using the same image and db ..

How may I adjust x y (of different screen sizes and densities) obtained OnTouchListener to match or be close to the ones in the db (with some tolerance) in order to get relevant information from the db?

I have tried using %  of total width and height to adjust x y as you saw in my code, but the results varied from screen size to another and were not close to the ones in the db.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: How are `x` and `y` defined in the database? What is the system in which those coordinates are specified?

Comment: Why don't you make invisible buttons with the right coordinates in the right areas?

Comment: I solved the issue ... It's a bit complex ... I will post  a very itersting solution tomorrow morning

Answer (score 1):

The solution required some analysis:

**1. Get screen size**

```
public static int getScreenX (Context context){
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int maxWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        return  maxWidth;
    }

    public static int getScreenY (Context context){
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        int maxHight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        return  maxHight;
    }
```

**2. get image xy**

```
image_IV.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    x = event.getX();
                    y = event.getY();
                    view.onTouchEvent(event);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

**3. calculate xy relative to screen size**

```
double ScreenX = Utils.getScreenX(context);
double ScreenY = Utils.getScreenY(context);
double xPer = x / ScreenX;
 double yPer = y / ScreenY;
```

**4. do some excel work to estimate screen size basis used in db**
[image]

**5. add screen size results to project**

```
double DBScreenX = 0;
                double DBScreenY = 0;
                if (LandScape) {
                    DBScreenX = 465;
                    DBScreenY = 280;
                } else {
                    DBScreenX = 480;
                    DBScreenY = 822;
                }
```

**6. add some tolerance around 15dp**

```
 public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
            return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        }
    double Talorance = Utils.dpToPx(15);
```

**7. calculate adjust xy and determine range using  tolerance**

```
  // X axis
                double xPer = x / ScreenX;
                double Adjustedx = xPer * DBScreenX;
                double MinX = Adjustedx - Talorance;
                double MaxX = Adjustedx + Talorance;

                // Y axis
                double yPer = y / ScreenY;
                double Adjustedy = yPer * DBScreenY;
                double MinY = Adjustedy - Talorance;
                double MaxY = Adjustedy + Talorance;
```

**8. get info from db based on adjuted xy range**

```
public int getSorahNo (int page, double minX, double maxX, double minY, double maxY) {
        int sorahNo = 1000;
        open();
        Cursor c = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + Contract.QuranTable.COLUMN_SORAH + " FROM " + Contract.QuranTable.TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + Contract.QuranTable.COLUMN_PAGE + " = " + page + " AND " +
                Contract.QuranTable.COLUMN_X + " BETWEEN " + minX + " AND " + maxX + " AND " +
                Contract.QuranTable.COLUMN_Y + " BETWEEN " + minY + " AND " + maxY, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                sorahNo = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Contract.QuranTable.COLUMN_SORAH));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        if( sorahNo == 1000){
            Log.w("getSorahNo ...", "Not successful ... Could not find Sorah based on x y" );
        } else {
            Log.w("getSorahNo ...", "is successful ... Sorah No = " + sorahNo);
        }

        close();
        return sorahNo;
    }
```